# links won't work on carousel in chrome on desktop

Tags: javascript, css

The blue buttons/links with "Learn More" in the main slider aren't clickable in Chrome on desktop.  If I scroll down and then up, then they work.
http://utilitycommunications.oiw9.com/index.htm

Comment: Please add relevant code to this question -- most of us don't want to debug your entire website without insight.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your class `rd-parallax-layer` is on top of your button. Which makes it not clickable.

One solution is to make display of `rd-parallax-layer` to `display:none` but I'm not sure whether it can create implications to other functionalities.

Another solution is you can play around the `z-index` value.